# Is it halachically problematic to call something "Karma"?

Tags: halacha, words, avodah-zarah, hinduism

Is the idea behind karma avodah zarah amd therefore prohibited to be used?

Comment: You're asking about "terms such as 'karma' and 'zen'" without specifying what you mean by that. Do you mean nouns? Words that start with consonants? Please [edit] to clarify what terms you're asking about and this can be reopened to answerers.